# After upgrading Craft CMS, is there a receipt to print out?

Tags: upgrades

The in-app process of upgrading a Craft licence is smooth, but leaves no paper trail (<s>not even a confirmation email</s>). 
All I've found is a date of registration in the admin panel sidebar, without even stating the Craft licence type (client or pro).

Is there away to obtain a somewhat formal proof of purchase, like a receipt, that I can pass along to a client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of a few weeks ago we added a "proper" PDF invoice attached to the receipt email that works for most people's cases.

We don't currently capture anything like your company information during the checkout process, so if you need that on the invoice, or you placed your purchase before we started attaching the invoice, hit us up at support@buildwithcraft.com and we can regenerate the invoice for you.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that this is an inappropriate place to bring it up, I think it'd be helpful if some identifying info, like the related domain name, could appear on the invoice. I've had trouble accounting for different licenses after the fact, and any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: Except there are all of the people who purchase it locally (craft.dev), with the intention of pushing the license.key file to production.  The proper solution is for us to get full user account/license management up on buildwithcraft.com, which is on our list.

Comment: Good point. My last purchase was from a local craft.dev subdomain, but I can see how this could be more confusing than helpful in the grand scheme. I guess I'll just have to continue using my brain for now.

Comment: This new PDF is basically what I was looking for – a proof of purchase to share with the client.

Answer (score 6):

You should receive an email after purchasing a Craft license. Maybe double check your email details and/or your spam folder.

Anyway, if you email the guys at support@buildwithcraft.com they will sort out a receipt for you.

Comment: D'oh ...just found it now, I expected Pixel&Tonic as sender, not Craft. (I'll upvote as soon as I have the privileges to.) — But the question remains, as colloquial as the mail is worded («every time you purchase Craft, an angel gets its wings»): is there a receipt page within the CMS?

Comment: Great :) There's not a receipt page within Craft, the email is the only automatic receipt. If that's not enough, you could pass your thoughts onto Pixel & Tonic, they're good listeners.